# Multiple output flyback converter simulation in Advanced Design System

Tags: transformer, inductor, inductance, flyback

I am trying to simulate with Advanced Design System (ADS) a multiple output (one primary winding, three secondary windings) flyback converter (see the image).

[image: Flyback converter]

But I cannot find a component in ADS library to do that...

I also tried to replace the transformer with four inductances mutually coupled (with three "mutual inductance" component). The problem is that the "mutual inductance" component from ADS library requires two parameters: the coupling coefficient k (from 0 to 1) and the mutual inductance M (expressed in Henry). How can I translate the turns ratio (n=N2/N1) of the transformer into the mutual inductance M for the coupled inductors?

Thanks in advance!

Giorgio

Answer (score 1):

You need to know the inductance of the primary winding. It's a design parameter. Once you have that, your secondary winding inductance will be (N2/N1)^2*Lprim.

Also, pro tip: Set your mutual inductance to 1 and draw the leakage inductance separately. Easier to see and understand.